# How do I efficiently search in SQL CE for nearby geographical nodes that are road junctions?

Tags: indexing, sql-server-ce, storage, spatial

I have the following query:

```
var nodes = DB.Nodes
              .Where(x =>    x.Lon > 486400
                          && x.Lon < 486600
                          && x.Lat > 5025100
                          && x.Lat < 5025300)
              .Join(DB.RoadNodes, x => x.Id, y => y.NodeId, (x, y) => x);
```

This searches all the nodes in `DB.Nodes` near a certain location, then it checks whether the node is a road junction by taking a join with `DB.RoadNodes`; however, this takes several seconds which is slow.

It looks like I have to do two things here:

1. Optimize the `Where` part which takes `~5` seconds on its own, I heard something about Spatial?
2. Optimize the `Join` part which takes a remaining `~15` seconds on its own, I need an index, right?

So I have two questions about this:

1. **How can I do spatial storage and searching in SQL Server Compact Edition?**

   If this is unsupported, how do I work around this issue?
2. **Which columns do I need to index for this query to work sufficiently?**

   It seems like indexing the NodeId of RoadNodes doesn't really improve the query.

Please note that I am restricted to SQL CE as I intend to run this on a Windows Phone 7.

Also node that I need to take an `Unique()` from that, which makes the query slightly longer but I guess that shouldn't be an issue if the query itself runs fast. It's just that he join introduces double results, or should I do the Join in another way?